# modulo missing in glsl 1.1 - how to wok around

Tags: math, opengl-es, glsl

0:13(22): error: operator '%' is reserved in GLSL 1.10 (GLSL 1.30 or GLSL ES 3.00 required)

somewhat nonplussed to hit this error!

I'm initially wanting to wrap texture coordinates to keep them in the range 0-1 - but modulo is such a useful function I could do with a general purpose replacement!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's a built-in function for the modulo operation, called `mod()`. It takes two arguments. The first one can be a vector as well as a float. For example, if `x`, `y` and `r` are float variables, and `v1` and `v2` variables of type `vec3`:

```
r = mod(x, y);  // calculates x % y
v2 = mod(v1, y);  // calculates component wise v2[i] = v1[i] % y
```

There is also a more specialized `fract()` function that calculates the modulo with divisor 1.0.

Comment: great that just what I needed! - Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Well, first of all in implementations that *do* support `%`, it is an integer operation just like most sensible languages (Java is the oddball). What you want here appears to be floating-point.

All versions of OpenGL ES support [`mod (...)`](http://www.khronos.org/opengles/sdk/docs/man3/html/mod.xhtml), this should do what you need.